# Which electrical outlets can I use?

Tags: code-golf

In North America, most electrical outlets/receptacles follow standards set by [NEMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NEMA_connector). For this challenge, you'll be given a few properties of a device you need to plug in, and your program (or function) should return all of the outlets that would be compatible.

For this challenge, an outlet has three properties: voltage, current rating, and grounding.

**I/O:**

Input will consist of a voltage, current usage, and grounding requirements for some device. The first two are positive integers, and the third can be represented by a boolean (though you are allowed to represent it in any reasonable way).

The output should be a list of outlets which are compatible, following the rules below. Each outlet's name is formatted as `NN-nn`, with `NN` and `nn` being numbers. All outlets should either be returned as strings with this formatting, or arrays of `[NN, nn]`. You can return the compatible outlets in an array, or separated with spaces/newlines/commas, or via any other reasonable method.

**Requirements:**

In order for an outlet to be compatible with the inputted device, it must meet three requirements:

- The voltage should be within ±10% of the device's voltage
- The current rating should be at least as high as the device's current usage
- If the device requires a grounded outlet, the outlet must be grounded (otherwise it may or may not be)

**Outlets:**

These are the outlets your program must be able to handle:

```
1-15     120    15     
2-15     240    15     
2-20     240    20     
2-30     240    30     
5-15     120    15    G
5-20     120    20    G
5-30     120    30    G
6-15     240    15    G
6-20     240    20    G
6-30     240    30    G
6-50     240    50    G
7-15     277    15    G
7-20     277    20    G
7-30     277    30    G
7-50     277    50    G
10-30    240    30     
10-50    240    50     
11-20    240    20     
11-30    240    30     
11-50    240    50     
12-20    480    20     
14-15    240    15    G
14-30    240    30    G
14-50    240    50    G
14-60    240    60    G
```

The first column is the name of the outlet, followed by the voltage, then the current rating, then a `G` if it's grounded. Some of these may be slightly inaccurate.

**Test Cases:**

Formatted with a voltage, then current usage, then a `G` for grounded or an `x` for ungrounded. Some do not have any compatible outlets.

```
120    16    G    5-20, 5-30
260    5     x    2-15, 2-20, 2-30, 6-15, 6-20, 6-30, 6-50, 7-15, 7-20, 7-30, 7-50, 10-30, 10-50, 11-20, 11-30, 11-50, 14-15, 14-30, 14-50, 14-60
260    5     G    6-15, 6-20, 6-30, 6-50, 7-15, 7-20, 7-30, 7-50, 14-15, 14-30, 14-50, 14-60
260    35    x    6-50, 7-50, 10-50, 11-50, 14-50, 14-60
480    10    x    12-20
108    10    x    1-15, 5-15, 5-20, 5-30
528    20    x    12-20
249    50    G    6-50, 14-50, 14-60
250    50    G    6-50, 7-50, 14-50, 14-60
304    10    x    7-15, 7-20, 7-30, 7-50
480    10    G    
480    25    x
400    10    x
600    10    x
180    10    x
80     10    x
```

**Other:**

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes per language wins!

Comment: Can we take input as an array ([voltage,current,grounding])?

Comment: @Ausername Sure, the order/method which you take those three don't matter at all, as long as their reasonable.

Comment: Minor complaint: your data makes NEMA 14 outlets equivalent to NEMA 6 ones, but actual NEMA 14 outlets can provide both 120V and 240V, unlike NEMA 6, and there's also a missing distinction between single-phase and 3-phase.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I considered adding some rules to account for those, but I didn't want to make the challenge overly complicated.

Answer (score 9):

## JavaScript (ES10), 159 bytes

Same logic as my original answer, but with the data stored as a string with several unprintable characters.

```javascript
(v,r,g)=>[..."_Î^~248ÕScž"].flatMap(x=>(x=x.charCodeAt(),n+=x>>6,V=(120<<x/16%4)%683,R=~(x/2&7)*10%65,-R<r|x&g|(V-v)**2>V*V/100?[]:n+[R]),n=1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVDNbtNAEJYQp1yQoJVaTqNI7e4mG2d345/QZFMhBDlxSSRfUoMsx0lTRXawTWRE6RMguMANeA7O9E36AjxCWG/StE2QEJb8jebbmW9mvjN/7qdBMplltSgehouRXOA5TeiYyM7AMIzyg9ePdi8/3bv/6uHO3oUwm5df9/u7@8GvHzt7j8ueMZr62Ut/hnPZUX9uBKd@8kwJPc0woVFV5p2OTV2JuWDtdl7n9oFJDuxmg/bkBc7r4tAhFc4ObIvWeu3kPD8cn2O3NieViui4FbfOGTseeEdRddDzlKDkZJGEb95OkhCjUYqIkYT@8MVkGvbfRQFmxMjifpZMojEmRjqbTjJcPonKxBjFyXM/OMUpyA68LwEMYE4hoTCmEOazMMjCIXggIV211QGqddICV3HVeQt6RUxa0FVxDFIC6qKW0klCJQkj7FLoUegS4yyeRBhRQKR4DuIojaehMY3HeLCeiAYIqrq1CsiDIsFaSN4scwzo98/PV9@@KERwBOjq@0dEvJX@SYaIGvCBLJSzoD5uF9gtwKoJRhU2WEnY@tEqAPICRI1bVGFRIlQJBVsztmbsFWMpdDTvaN7RvKN5znSigs64LlChsQyaNHWvCo1ltiLtjY30uv89/5/iDWt97rWUdWdja7PRbC5NZOtGXlhU4qy5yevh1grXRltCF4pNAWE@0eeyW@duTRfL560iZ7u0wcyNhf5u092LtOY1JW7cKZls8@6SvU3xLXdKS@Y29Qc)

---

## JavaScript (ES10),  <sub><s>200 190 186</s></sub>  181 bytes

Expects `(voltage, current, ground)`, where `ground` is a Boolean value. Returns an array of strings in `NN-nn` format.

```javascript
(v,r,g)=>"0F5F1315CE02045E1214187E323438D519531519639E14181A".match(/../g).flatMap(x=>(x='0x'+x,n+=x>>6,V=(120<<x/16%4)%683,R=~(x/2&7)*10%65,-R<r|x&g|(V-v)**2>V*V/100?[]:n+[R]),n=1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVDBbtpAEL3zFSMksrt4sXfXXhsCJqpa4NQLkXwhHCwwriNqU@MiR037BZV66bH9j35PfqCfQNcLIYmpVNWS32jfzLx5M7fhLtwu8mRTdNJsGe1X/h7vaE5j4g@bbCzH3Oby9YgJ5sgRF9zhXW9kC9uxu28k70mV5T3X7o2qDH/VNN@HxeIdtkzTiom5WofF23CDS3@ofsRKZJQ0NfxyOHRp4GMu2GBQWtxtOaTldm069b/g0hIXHmlz1nIl7UwH@X15Ed/joLMj7bYYBu3A4oxdzeaXqTGbzglNfU72efThY5JHGK22iJh5FC7HyTq6vksXmBGzyK6LPEljTMztZp0UuHmTNpW/LB@Fyu4W/CF8agDMYEchpxBTiMpNtCiiJczBh@2xzQIwLNKHQHHGrg/TKuZ9mKgYg@8DmqC@0skjJQkrHFCYUpgQ8zZLUowoIFKlF1m6zdaRuc5iPDtNRDMEhm41AM2hemAt5D@ZuQL0@9e3hx/fFSK4BPTw8ysi86P@TYGIGvCZ7NVlQX3crXBSgewIRhXarCFcnZQVQFmB6HBJFVYlQpVQcDXjasY9MlKhp3lP857mPc1zph8q6BfXBSrYh6BJR/eqYB9eR9KtOdJ2/3v@P8VteVr3UUq@cCzrjU73cER2auTViRqcdeu8Hi6PeDq0FLpQ1AWE09Prsmfrnk0Xh/RZkXdeajOnZujvZ3q5kdZ8pMTTdRoOq@/dcM8pfnadxoF5Tv0B)

### How?

#### Encoding format

Each outlet is encoded as a byte `x` whose bit-mask is `DDVVRRRG` with:

- `DD` = difference between the leading outlet ID and the previous leading outlet ID
- `VV` = voltage: `[120,240,480,277]` mapped to `[0,1,2,3]`
- `RRR` = current rating: `[20,30,50,60,15]` mapped to `[1,2,4,5,7]`
- `G` = flag set if there's no ground

For instance, the outlet `10-30` is encoded as `0xD5 = 0b11010101`:

```javascript
11 01 010 1
 |  |   | |
 |  |   | +--> no ground
 |  |   +----> rating 2 (30A)
 |  +--------> voltage 1 (240V)
 +-----------> previous ID + 3 (7 + 3 = 10)
```

The whole data is stored as a single string of two-nibble hexadecimal values, which are split with a `match()`.

#### Decoding

The leading ID is updated with:

```javascript
n += x >> 6
```

Because \$277\$ is \$960\bmod683\$, the voltage is decoded with:

```javascript
V = (120 << x / 16 % 4) % 683
```

Because \$15\$ is \$80\bmod65\$, the current rating is decoded with:

```javascript
R = -~(x / 2 & 7) * 10 % 65
```

Comment: I don't know how this works, but I am in awe...

Comment: @Ausername I've added an explanation.

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>310</s> 294 bytes

```javascript
(x,y,z)=>[...'demu`hpaiqybjrzu}mu}oaqyY'].map((x,i)=>[[120,240,277,480][(s=x.charCodeAt())%4],h=[12,3,4,6,10][(s-s%8)/8-11]*5,(s-s%4)/4%2,[[...'11000300100010003010012000'].map(x=>+x).slice(0,i+2).reduce((a,b)=>a+b),h]]).filter(m=>9*m[0]/10<=x&&11*m[0]/10>=x&&y<=m[1]&&(z?!m[2]:1)).map(x=>x[3])
```

[[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZBNbsIwEIX3vUUXgA2DGTsGQoWpqp6isizVQGiCEgL5qQJSz04dCgukmoXjPH1vPG9ma79tuSqSfTXc5evovFFn0sARTlQtNGOst46y@jPe2@RwXG6LU/2T1T@5PRw/eoZldk@cO2m9mgsEId2ZTkGGaDQpVcNWsS3e3cNvFaG0Iw3EyjkhAAkT4BfXsOyEdBQOOTf9MVy0pCPZEaAvCThHxACxvf5@3dd1Q7xGaNRi0FBWpskqIgjJQFBWROvaKWJh6dLZwZJCbAxlmyStooJkajHrZxrNiONcNd0u5ze5aOVxrjLNTbdLTq/PmRbmhVN6a9bowNDzKt@VeRqxNP8iG9JOzydQFXVE6dM9ExOEMWxsWvqYtyzw1bkNu/V5IMfQD8ciBOGDQs5gjJ48DvhYgNLf8Zr138KWCe@Q@GDIySPIH63njp1/AQ)

Arnauld beat me to this, and did it better, but I put two hours of work into this...

The string compression is interesting.
Above, each character in

```javascript
demu`hpaiqybjrzu}mu}oaqyY
```

is the binary data for:

```javascript
d
To char code is 100
To binary is 1100100

1 - just on the start
100 - Represents current 15 - 100 => 15, 101 => 20, 110 => 30, 111 => 50, 011 => 60
1 - No ground (0 for ground)
00 - Voltage 120 - 00 => 120, 01 => 240, 10 => 277, 11 => 480.
```

And in this way each outlet is encoded into a single character.

### Explanation

```javascript
(x,y,z)=>                                        // declare function
[...'demu`hpaiqybjrzu}mu}oaqyY']                 // see above on compression
.map((x,i)=>                                     //map by item / index
[                                                //return array of:
[120,240,277,480]                                // possible voltages
[(s=x.charCodeAt())%4],                          //decipher from string & get correct value
h=                                               //save following for use in name
[12,3,4,6,10]                                    //possible current values, 
[(s-s%8)/8-8]*5,                                 //get correct one from decoded string item and multiply by 5
(s-s%4)/4%2,                                     // get ground boolean
[[...'11000300100010003010012000']               // change in first part of string each time - sum of first m will be first part of name m
.map(x=>+x)                                      // to array of numbers
.slice(0,i+2).reduce((a,b)=>a+b)                 //sum of first [index]
,h]                                              // + '-' + h, the current value we saved earlier, produces name
])
//This is where all the magic happens, up to here is just data compression
.filter(m=>                                      //filter m by if all are true:
9*m[0]/10<=x                                     //9/10 of m[0] (voltage) is less than given voltage
&&11*m[0]/10>=x                                  // 11/10 of m[0] (voltage) is greater than given voltage (so voltage is within 10%)
&&y<=m[1]                                        // given current is less than or equal to m[1] (current)
&&(z?                                            //if breaker required
!m[2]                                            //check if breaker
:1)                                              //else always true
).map(x=>x[3])                                   // convert to list of names
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 115 bytes

```
≔¹⁰⁰εＮθＮηＮζＩＥΦＩ⪪”)⧴→ＷuJＳN4⊘Ｒf⎚θ⊕∧H,\`m↖⊗？Yς×≧üλθ▷TE⦄→×◧Àλ≧”⁴¬∨›ζ‹⁵﹪÷ιε⁸∨›η﹪ιε‹·¹↔⁻¹∕θ⎇⁼⁷÷ιε²⁷⁷×¹²⁰⎇⁼¹¹÷ιε²⊕﹪⊖÷ιε⁴↨ιε
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZDdagIxEIXvfYrg1QTSMomb3YJXtrZFqLagLxA11EDMapIV6stvZ8W2og0MOd8k5@RntTFxVRvftqOU3GcAiSiY5cPeJOyaPGu2Sxthf8WbKz4Sf0QXMjyZlGFqdvDifKaVE8933mXoo5QaVVcKUQ0QNWlNWpMuSZeky05rxIq4Iq6IK40SB1Q0S0U1OEVJypGF1LIgLoiLEvuCFZwLNqszvEd4jdZ01zgK9mZTAi3YtF43voZJyGN3cGsLrnuvYA@88114Nr97Tzv4OQLvpWCjZap9ky1MXWgSUOccthdsYWMw8Que943xCSrBrs6iJFVRe@G2lrwKbzxS/mvqmqtotzZku4bz5cb2r3Xroc@4GII9mvSzyPmwbVWJPd2T7d3BfwM) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes the groundedness as an integer, `1` = grounded, `0` = ungrounded and outputs in array format `[[N, nn], ...]` (string format is possible at the cost of 1 byte). Explanation:

```
≔¹⁰⁰ε
```

Save the value `100` as it gets used a lot. (Charcoal only has predefined variables for `10` and `1000`.)

```
ＮθＮηＮζ
```

Input the voltage, current and groundedness.

```
ＩＥΦＩ⪪”)⧴→ＷuJＳN4⊘Ｒf⎚θ⊕∧H,\`m↖⊗？Yς×≧üλθ▷TE⦄→×◧Àλ≧”⁴¬
```

Split the compressed string of outlets in `NNnn` format into individual outlets in decimal, and filter out any that fail any of the following tests:

```
∨›ζ‹⁵﹪÷ιε⁸
```

The device needs to be grounded, but `NN` (modulo `8`) is less than `5`.

```
∨›η﹪ιε
```

The device requires more than `nn` current.

```
‹·¹↔⁻¹∕θ⎇⁼⁷÷ιε²⁷⁷×¹²⁰⎇⁼¹¹÷ιε²⊕﹪⊖÷ιε⁴
```

Dividing the device's voltage by the receptacle's voltage results in a value outside the range `0.9`..`1.1`. The receptacle's voltage is calculated as `NN` (modulo `4`, or `4` if `NN` is a multiple of `4`, or `2` if `NN` is `11`) multiplied by `120`, unless `NN` is `7`, in which case `277` is used instead.

```
↨ιε
```

Split the `NNnn` integer into separate `NN` and `nn` values by converting into base `100`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/),  <s>155</s> 150 bytes

```ruby
f=->v,a,g{z=0
"yQxwxwTxwuUuuwubvuw	 xwu".bytes{|i|z+=121-i
(v-q=(16<<z/140)*7.5%683)**2<=q*q/100&&g*4<=(t=z/10%14)%8&&a<=(c=z%10*5+15)&&(p [t+1,c])}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVLLcoIwFF2XRb8hgwMjGDQ3kEA70n/oTLtyXKijjpuqFcTnt9NLhBLUzrSLZpHLOZxzH0k@0/E@z2ex97KlIzo/HmJmmPvXXfa4y952Wfqeplk63qbZA0Fkdsf7ZLo5nhanQycGDt7CaG@9ddwG2e8fehAwxw27wpKR77gu78drd90Dxmx77gb9uJ3EKGIWBI4V2fYImUl8sIC5ogPCse32igySDtDJ0Dmf81WabIg5GwBnFCSFIcHVEh5CIjyfmYb2zzAqOZeMCsqUmrS4B4ISrkwcTZRIxUjFyJIRuIeKDxUfKj5UPDAFMCgESoDBvwRFBsqLwb@gkpSqx6qh6xahbPHPDf2iWpG7Wc@vzqRVZReNqcQPuSpfnS2I8MxZlQ2Ksy3ENV1LgUW6VPUtyr1xjZqudgseUX5bqEFrQwZPFLsHfcibgTSN5kTq2hne9@vKOoHPAm3M@/dW2Bu6yk4@lmSZJgjIZLSZbp7rsyxfSCG@cFy9I/xm2hUgllcYoib@hiaW/c/8l5V/AQ)

The magic string contains one character 14 and one tab (character 9).

A function taking 3 inputs: volts, amps, ground (where ground is 0 or 1.)

Prints a list of two-element arrays to stdout. These are ordered by rated voltage, so the ordering of the output may differ a little from the test cases in the question, but they are all there.

**Commented code**

```ruby
f=->v,a,g{z=0                         #Input voltage, current and grounding. Set z=0
"yQxwxwTxwuUuuwubvuw     xwu".        #Magic string, one byte per outlet spec.
     bytes{|i|z+=121-i                #Iterate through bytes and increment z.
     (v-q=(16<<z/140)*7.5%683)**2<=   #16*7.5=120V. rightshift by z/140 to get 240, 480 or 960%683=277V. Find the difference from input and square it.
     q*q/100&&                        #If the difference is 1/10 of the outlet rating or less... (NB. q/10 must be squared to compare with the above) 
       g*4<=(t=z/10%14)%8&&           #Extract the outlet type (minus 1.) Grounded outlets have t%8 greater or equal to 4. If grounding acceptable....
         a<=(c=z%10*5+15)&&           #Decode the current rating. If acceptable...
           (p [t+1,c])}               #Print the outlet spec: type and current rating.
}
```

I decided to order by voltage rating as there are only 4 possible values, hence only 3 steps in voltage, only 2 of which result in nonprintable characters in the magic string.

Realising that subtracting 1 from the outlet type and taking modulo 8 always gives a number of 4 or greater for grounded outlets and never for ungrounded ones was handy as I didn't have to compress this.

Answer (score 2):

## Excel, 220 bytes

135 bytes for this formula.

```
=LET(f,B1:J1*B2:J6,r,A2:A6,v,XLOOKUP(f,L1:L4,M1:M4,240),TEXTJOIN(",",,IF((ABS(A8-v)<=v/10)*(B8<=r)*((MOD(f,10)>3)+1-C8)*f,f&"-"&r,"")))
```

68 bytes for this array of cells that shows the valid pairs of numbers before and after the dash.

```
    1   2   5   6   7   10  11  12  14
15  1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0
20  0   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1
30  0   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1
50  0   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   1
60  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
```

17 byte for this array of cells that maps the numbers before the dash to voltages other than 240.

```
 1 120
 5 120
 7 277
12 480
```